# there was an error while fetching events in fullcalendar.js

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

I have used the "fullcalendar.js".When i click in previous and next button frequently then it will show me error like "there was an error while fetching events!.I got idea that it will give error because of it try to get much data frequently and it is not able to handle instantly till previous data get completed.Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `async:false` in calender initialization.It will solve the problem.